# Solving BSOD inaccessible_boot_device for cloned Windows 11 OS on external SSD

Tags: windows-11, bsod

I cloned Windows 11 on my work PC (HP Omen) to use on days I work from home on my own iMac (2012), thus I don't have to carry the 4kg Omen from the office.
I used AOMEI for cloning with migrationOS function. A simple procedure, you don't need even any guidance to get it well.
Afterwards I ran the cloned OS on the same computer (HP Omen) to test if it was successful? Then got a blue screen and this message… **inaccessible_boot_device**!

A lot of research and trials followed to treat the problem all described in **attempts**. All failed/unsuccessful/abortive! Hence a big surprise for me…
When I put the cloned SSD on my home computer (iMac (2012)) - everything worked right away.

*Someone will say, you got your goal achieved, what’s s the matter…*

I have a new idea now, to use the cloned Windows 11 on external SSD for third-party software and my own experiments with them. So I keep the HP Omen OS nice and clean, untouched.

**Attempts**:

- Changing boot mode for the PCI devices from UEFI — doesn't make sense to my case.
- Save mode - boots and works.
- Disable driver license check - stops with “bsod”.
- Windows Startup Repair - It couldn't find any issues.
- Using the same Windows installation media, Bootrec /fixMbr followed by Bootrec /fixBoot. I have also tried Bootrec /RebuildBcd on a separate attempt — no combination has returned any bad results.
- Booting on a different computer from the original one (for instance Surface 5) — boots and works fine.

**Purpose**:

- The cloned OS SSD to boot on the original computer (HP Omen), where it was created.

Comment: I am pretty sure you can do what you want with a Hyper-V Windows 11 VM.   Create one, make a good backup for recovery and experiment as you wish.

Comment: How have you booted a PC HP disk on an iMac? Sounds pretty impossible to me.

Comment: Windows 11 cannot boot from an external drive unless it’s a Windows 2 Go installation and properly configured within the registry. Windows 2 Go is officially not supported by Microsoft.

Comment: “When I put the cloned SSD on my home computer (iMac (2012)) - everything worked right away.” What do you mean? You actually booted a 12 year old 2012 iMac off of Windows 11 cloned to an SSD? Sounds impossible.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your response. VM is an alternative solution that can always be implemented. But unfortunately it doesn't answer my question.

Comment: Thanks Ramhound. This makes sense. By following this logic, we should expect Windows 11 cloned not to boot from the SSD at all. But it goes. Proved on two different systems, MS Surface 5 and iMac.

Comment: Hey Giacomo! yes, it really does not even not worse than on a HP. If you are really curious I can film it for you.

Comment: Sadly, I don't have a solution yet, but could you recommend links where I can read more about the matter? That would be grate. Cheers